# Joining two aggregate queries from the same table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

I have two queries, both are aggregated from the same table. I'm not sure if I have to join these two queries together or if it can be done with one select statement. The goal is to output a table that aggregates total charges and total refunds for each student.

Query #1:

```
select 
    s.learners_id, sum(charge.total_amount) charge_amount
from 
    fact_student_transactions_t charge 
inner join 
    dim_students_t s on s.students_sk_id = charge.students_sk_id
left join 
    object_statuses_t os on os.object_statusid = charge.transaction_status_id
where 
    os.status_name = 'Success' 
    and charge.tran_type = 'CHARGE' 
    and charge.curr_in = 1
group by 
    s.learners_id
```

Query #2:

```
select 
    s.learners_id, sum(refund.total_amount) refund_amount
from 
    fact_student_transactions_t refund
inner join 
    dim_students_t s on s.students_sk_id = refund.students_sk_id
left join 
    object_statuses_t os on os.object_statusid = refund.transaction_status_id
where 
    os.status_name = 'Success' 
    and refund.tran_type = 'Refund' 
    and refund.trans_description not in ('Amount Successfully Transfered to Prepaid Balance.', 'Amount Successfully Transfered.') 
    and refund.payment_method != 'Transfer' 
    and refund.curr_in = 1
group by 
    s.learners_id
```

Comment: FYI, you have a `LEFT JOIN` to `object_statuses_t`, however, you reference the column `os.status_name` in the `WHERE` without handling `NULL`s, meaning that the `JOIN` is an implicit `INNER JOIN`. Is that intended? If not, that clause should be in the `ON`. If it is, why use a `LEFT JOIN` when it's intended to be an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: `st` is not defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oops, that's a mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: @Larnu You are correct, left join is not necessary here. Its a habit of mine to use left join with the objects table, but in this case I'm filtering it, so left join doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Also, because of the nature of the `where` clause, the `left join` is unnecessary -- the unmatched records are filtered out anyway.

So:

```
select s.learners_id,
       sum(case when st.tran_type = 'CHARGE' then st.total_amount else 0 end) as charge_amount,
       sum(case when st.tran_type = 'Refund' and 
                     st.trans_description not in ('Amount Successfully Transfered to Prepaid Balance.', 'Amount Successfully Transfered.') 
and
                     st.payment_method <> 'Transfer'
                then st.total_amount else 0 
           end) as refund_amount
from fact_student_transactions_t st join
     dim_students_t s 
     on s.students_sk_id = t.students_sk_id join
     object_statuses_t os 
     on os.object_statusid = t.transaction_status_id
where os.status_name = 'Success' and 
      st.curr_in = 1 and
      st.tran_type in ('CHARGE', 'Refund')
group by s.learners_id
```

Comment: Thanks this really helps. Heads up, I had to adjust the alias "t" back to "st" in your solution, just looks like a typo.